# Make substitutions without specifying the object

Tags: replacement

I have a piece of code that outputs terms like

```
vect[k,i]^2 vect[q,i]^2*bunch_of_other_stuff
```

where vect is a function that defines a vector, where k and q are the names of the vector and i and j are the spatial indices. I wanna automatically cast this in the form

```
vect[k,i] vect[q,i] vect[k,j] vect[q,j]*bunch_of_other_stuff
```

I know that this can be easily done using

```
vect[k,i]^2 vect[q,i]^2*bunch_of_other_stuff/.vect[k,i] vect[q,i] vect[k,j] vect[q,j]*bunch_of_other_stuff
```

Nevertheless, the problem is that where i wrote q above i can have other letters, and the same happens with i and j. So, how can I implement

```
vect[anything1,anything2]^2 vect[anything3,anything2]^2*->vect[anything1,anything2] vect[anything3,anything2] vect[anything1,another_letter] vect[anthing3,another_letter]
```

without specifying the names what takes the place of q and k?

Comment: Let `expr = vect[k, i]^2 vect[q, i]^2*boos;` and use `expr /. Power[vect[arg1_, arg2_], 2] :> 
  vect[arg1, arg2] vect[arg1, anotherletter]`?

Comment: ... also:  `expr /. Power[vect[arg1 : _, arg2 : _], 2] :> 
  vect[arg1, arg2] vect[arg1, anotherletter]` (see: [Docs >> Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) and [Introduction to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html))

Comment: This looks like a tensor question. I suggest you consider asking a different question about how to generate an explicit representation of a tensor contraction without using duplicate indices. Then you wouldn't have to worry about how to repair a tensor contraction where the indices occur more than twice.

Comment: @CarlWoll This is probably a good idea but the full source code has not been written by me, and I just wanna fix one crappy step in the middle without having to decipher everything